# Quaternion expansion

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, vector-spaces, definite-integrals

I have a    quaternion equation $ \psi(s)=Pe^{\frac{1}{2}k(s)}\tag 1$

**Given conditions and data**

1. Here P is a constant unit  Quaternion defined for 3D rotation matrix as

   $(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)  , p_4\in R \tag 2$,$Y= p_1i+p_2j+p_3k,Y\in R^3 \tag 3$ ,Y is a vector
2. Vector $k(s)=  \int_{0}^{s} \{((1-u)a_1+ub_1)i+((1-u)a_2+ub_2)j+((1-u)a_3+ub_3)k\}du\tag 4$

   All $a_i,b_i$ are 
   constants. I am bit confused with the exponential expansion of this vector.   I got stucked because of that

**Question**

1. Basic definition of vector exponent is given as follows

   $\begin{eqnarray}
   \exp( {\bf v}) & = & {\bf 1}+ {\bf v}+ \frac{1}{2!}{{\bf v}}^2 + \frac{1}{3!}{\bf v}^3 + \ldots \\
   & = & [ {\bf 1}+ \frac{1}{2!}({\bf v}\cdot{\bf v}) + \frac{1}{4!}({\bf v}\cdot{\bf v})^2 + . . . ] + \\
     &   & \frac{{\bf v}}{\surd({\bf v}\cdot{\bf v})} [\surd({\bf v}\cdot{\bf v})+\frac{1}{3!}\surd({\bf v}\cdot{\bf v})^3+\ldots ] \\
     & = & {\bf 1}\cosh(\surd({\bf v}\cdot{\bf v})) + \frac{{\bf v}}{\surd({\bf v}\cdot{\bf v})} \sinh(\surd({\bf v}\cdot{\bf v})), \\
     & = & {\bf 1}\cosh(|{\bf v}|) + \frac{{\bf v}}{|{\bf v}|} \sinh(|{\bf v}|),
   \end{eqnarray}$

   **Is it possible to  write $e^{\frac{1}{2}k(s)}$ using the above vector exponent explantion as a quaternion**(beacuse of the form of final result $ {\bf 1}\cosh(|{\bf v}|) + \frac{{\bf v}}{|{\bf v}|} \sinh(|{\bf v}|) )$? **What could be the four elements of the  quaternion $\psi(s)$? Shall we  extract the four members of $\psi(s)$ from the product of matrix representation quaternion $P$ and quaternion $e^{\frac{1}{2}k(s)}$**

Comment: Your integral should be easy to compute. Then plug it into the formula you have for $\exp$. I don't see what the issue is. Also, we generally can't multiply or exponentiate vectors - call quaternions quaternions, not vectors.

Comment: That was a type error.. I just made it correct just seconds before you replied. Please check again. Thanks

Comment: "Your integral should be easy to compute. Then plug it into the formula you have for exp" That is ok.. But what is after that. beacuse I need to multiply that with P a quaterbion. But see the out put of exp. It is  $ {\bf 1}\cosh(|{\bf v}|) + \frac{{\bf v}}{|{\bf v}|} \sinh(|{\bf v}|) )$. How do I multiply that with P. By seeing that form $(t+vector)$. I thought I can write it as quaternion so that I can do multiplication easily with P using matrix representation of quaternion

Comment: When you think of a vector $v$ as a quaternion, $v^2=-v\cdot v$, where the $\cdot$ is the usual dot product of $\Bbb{R}^3$. It looks like you are not conversant with quaternion operations. Study [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) for starters. You see that because of the above sign error trig functions pop out instead of the hyperbolic ones.

Comment: I am a starter in quaternions. I am bit familiar with basic operations . But here I am confused coz $Pe^{(\frac{1}{2}v)}$ Basically ,I am bit confused about how do I multiply P with  $e^{(\frac{1}{2}v)}$. P is a quaternion but I am not sure what is $e^{(\frac{1}{2}v)}$. How to multiply a quaternion q with some thing like $e^{(\frac{1}{2}v)}$

Comment: One of the things the quaternion algebra says is that any **unit** vector $\vec{u}\in\Bbb{R^3}$ can take the role of the complex number $i$. So for all reals numbers $x$ we have
$$
e^{x\vec{u}}=\cos x+ \vec{u}\sin x.
$$ Just like $e^{xi}=\cos x+i\sin x$!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute $k$ and use the exponential expansion of a quarternion. Then compute $\psi$ by multiplying out each component of it from the components of the exponential expansion with $P$.

Comment: Yes I was asking the same..